# How to Pass State from List Selection in Modal to Parent in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I have a view where a user can see a list of items. When they click a button, a modal pops up with a List Selection where they can choose items. I would like these selections to update the list on the parent view.

I am using an ObservedObject for the SelectedItems:

```
class SelectedItems: ObservableObject, Hashable {
    @Published var items: [Item] = []

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(items)
    }

    init(items: [Item]) {
        self.items = items
    }
}
```

On the parent view, I simply loop through them:

```
...

@ObservedObject var selectedItems: SelectedItems

...

List(self.selectedItems.items) { item in
  Text(item.name)
}
```

The problem is in the modal view:

```
...

@ObservedObject var selectedItems: SelectedItems
var items: [Item]

...

List(items, id: \.self, selection: selectedItems) { item in
  Text(item.name)
}
.environment(\.editMode, .constant(EditMode.active))
```

I made sure that `selectedIngredients` conforms to `Hashable` as required by `List Selection`, but it's still throwing a number of errors.

The specific error in this case is Generic parameter `'SelectionValue' could not be inferred`.

I have been at this for a couple days and any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List` selection expects `Binding` to either one `Element` of listing sequence of to `Set<Element>`, so your case can be solved with the following approach

```
List(items, id: \.self, selection: Binding<Set<Item>>(
    get: { Set(self.selectedItems.items) },
    set: { self.selectedItems.items = Array<Item>($0) }
)) { item in
  Text(item.name)
}
.environment(\.editMode, .constant(EditMode.active))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have changed that code and can confirm that the `selectedItems` is being updated by printing out the value of `selectedItems.items` array after the modal is closed, but for some reason, it's still not showing up in the parent view list. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: I figured it out. For some reason, removing `List () {}` and just using a `ForEach() {}` on the parent view works. `List` doesn't seem to re-render when the `ObservedObject` is updated for some reason.